# I want to change where the Vim folder is located

Tags: microsoft-windows, installing

For example, if my path is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim

And I want it to be:

> C:\Users\~\Documents\Vim

How do I do that so I will still be able to call "gvim" on CMD, for example?

Comment: Uninstall Vim and then reinstall it with the path that you want?

Comment: Isn't there another way?

Comment: Yes, manually duplicating the steps of uninstalling and installing ;-) You probably don't *need* to do the uninstall step by the way, but having two Vim installations strikes me as a potential source of great confusion. Why do you want to do this "another way"?

Comment: Mainly to learn, I guess.

Comment: There's no problem with relocating the executable--the problem is relocating the plugin files. You might be able to solve that problem by setting the VIM environment variable to the new location of the vim74 directory.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to do that: you said it is to learn but I don't see what you want to learn precisely. Anyway maybe you'd be interested in [`:h 'runtimepath'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27runtimepath%27)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is, as @Carpetsmoker noted in the comments, to simply *uninstall gVim and reinstall it*, selecting the desired installation directory. Depending on your installation options, gVim may have made some registry modifications to establish file associations when initially installed. For example, the "Edit with Vim" context menu option for explorer is a key under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/*/shell/Vim/Command` with a value of `"C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim74\gvim.exe" "%1"`. Uninstalling and re-installing will ensure these keys have correct values.

You can, of course, simply move the entire `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim` folder somewhere else. If you do this, you'll have to at least fix up your `%PATH%` environment variable to include the new location, or `gvim` won't work. You'll also have to find and fix (or delete) any registry or similar associations you want to continue working or don't want to have any longer.

Uninstalling and re-installing is definitely the ideal option here. It's way less work and will result in a much less broken installation.